# How to show all records from one header number in one page

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

I have a report that shows the purchases of a client, grouping by invoice's header number.

I have this:

```
        Invoice
        1000001

        Ordered    Shipped    Remaining    Item Description
        1.00        1.00       1.00             test item
```

This and other data is showing in one page, but if one invoice has many items, the report show this:

```
        Invoice
        1000001

        Ordered    Shipped    Remaining    Item Description
        1.00        1.00       1.00             test item
        (page break)

        Invoice
        1000002

        Ordered    Shipped    Remaining    Item Description
        1.00        1.00       1.00             test item
        (page break)

         Invoice
         1000002

         Ordered    Shipped    Remaining    Item Description
         1.00        1.00       1.00             new cs
```

And I want to show this:

```
         Invoice
         1000001

         Ordered    Shipped    Remaining    Item Description
          1.00        1.00       1.00          test item
         (page break)

         Invoice
         1000002

         Ordered    Shipped    Remaining    Item Description
          1.00        1.00       1.00          test item
          1.00        1.00       1.00           new cs
```

I have this problem since one week ago and I don't have any ideas tho resolve this. I'm working in SSRS 2012 and SQL 2012

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you have tried and how it failed to meet your requirements?

Comment: I tried show the quantities in a separate group but the page break puts them in a separate page after all the first group, I want to show all quantities from the same Invoive in one page

Answer (score 0):

Create a List object. Group By the Invoice's Header # in the List object. Drag and drop your existing tablix into the list. Go to the Invoice group's properties and make sure the Page Break Between Each Instance of a Group box is checked on the Page Breaks tab.

Comment: Remove all other page breaks you may have in place with the original Tablix and its groups.